# Offset Match function in VBA/Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a userform where the value chosen in the combobox determines the range of an offset match function. The lookup value is entered within a textbox (TextBox1) in the same userform.

```
If ComboBox1 = "Something" Then
TryRun = Evaluate("Offset(Sheets('Sheet1').Range('B13'),MATCH(TextBox1.Value,Sheets('Sheet1').Range('B14:B33'),0),5)")
End If
```

Currently this returns the value of cell G15, what I need it to do however is to simply select that cell and paste the value of Textbox (TextBox2) in the userform.

This doesn't seem to work, 
`Cells(TryRun).Value = TextBox2`,
because it cannot find a defined object for 'TryRun'. However, seeing as this refers to a cell, I wouldn't know what to define it as.

Could anyone help me out?

I've tried Ahmed's U Vlookup solution to get this:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()

If Combobox1 = "Something" Then
TryRun = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(Textbox1.Text), Range("B14:G33"), 6, False)

    If IsEmpty(TryRun) Then
    Msgbox "nope"
    Textbox2.Text = "No Match found"
    Else
    Msgbox "almost..."
    TextBox2.Value = TryRun
    End If
   End If

End Sub
```

This results in Textbox2 returning value = 0 within the userform whilst nothing gets pasted through the vlookup function.

By removing the `on error` lines, the code stops working all together, with the faulty line being `TryRun = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(Textbox1.Text), Sheets("Stuff").Range("B14:G33"), 6, False)`. The error this results in is: Error 424, object required.

EDIT:

After removing `Dim TryRun As Long` I've come across the next stumbling block: Currently I'm returning "No Match Found" Instead of Try Run's value in the designated cell address.

EDIT 2:

Somehow, I'm returning the second messagebox  now in the `else` statement. Still no value being pasted in TryRun though.

Comment: Start from something simple and try to build a [MCVE]. Hint - it does not matter that you work in a `UserForm` at all. Nor that your sheet is `Sheet1`, `B13`, `TextBox1`, etc. For a MCVE hard-code all these values to something easy to reproduce. Or look at the [address](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) formula and try to write it somewhere. Have fun! :)

Comment: `Evaluate` is for running worksheet function formulas, not for VBA.

Comment: Please comment out 'Dim TryRun As Long'., (This is to be used with WorkSheetFunction.Match only since it returns offset row count)..What is the textBox1.Text when OKButton Clicked? Does the number exists in B14:B33 range

Comment: Error 424  on line 'TryRun=…..'  raises doubt about existence of Object TextBox1 on the Userform. Try "MsgBox  TextBox1.Text" before 'TryRun=….'

Comment: I've removed the 'Dim TryRun As Long' and added the messagebox. As of now, I'm getting a messagebox pop up with the value of Textbox1. Right after that, the random value I entered in Textbox2 gets overwritten by "No match found". No value has been pasted on the actual sheet.

Comment: This indicate range B14:B33 does not contain the exact number entered in textbox1 or range B14:B33 have non-numeric data type.

Comment: Seems highly unlikely, Vlookup is looking at an array between the values 1,2,...,20. The number I enter in textbox1 has always been in between 1 and 20. What's more, I've even tried to replace the `val("Textbox1.Text")` with static numbers instead to see if that'd work, but it didn't.

Comment: Kindly as a last resort go to Range B14:B33  and check whether cell contents are actually number  or Text (this happens when numbers are entered in text formatted cells)

Comment: If you are getting the 2nd msgbox after else statement, check for empty G column values.

Comment: @AhmedAU The cell contents in B14:B33 are considered numbers. A simple `=B14+15` confirmed this as well. I've since removed everything in the G column, and I'm currently returning the first msgbox after the else statement without the value of textbox2 being pasted after vlookup matches textbox1's value with the given range.

Answer (score 0):

As Evaluate is for running worksheet function formulas, not for VBA as commented by @Tim Williams. There are numerous way to solve the problem otherwise

You may try `WorksheetFunction.Match`

```
Dim TryRun As Long
On Error Resume Next
TryRun = WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, Sheet1.Range("B14:B33"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0

    If TryRun > 0 Then
    TextBox2.Text = Sheet1.Range("G" & 13 + TryRun).Value
    Else
    TextBox2.Text = " No Match found"
    End If
```

Or try `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`

```
On Error Resume Next
TryRun = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TextBox1.Text, Sheet1.Range("B14:G33"), 6, False)
' Vookup consider 1str column as 1, Col G will be 6
On Error GoTo 0

    If IsEmpty(TryRun) Then
    TextBox2.Text = " No Match found"
    Else
    TextBox2.Text = TryRun
    End If
```

A word of caution, it is assumed that only text type data is being searched. For numeric  type of data it please use `Val(TextBox1.Text)`

Comment: I'm attempting to utilize the VlookUp method, but it doesn't seem to prompt any sort of message nor is anything pasted. For clarity's sake:

     ` If Combobox1 = "Stuff" Then
       On Error Resume Next
        TryRun = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(TextBox1.Text), Sheets("Other Stuff").Range("B14:G33"), 6, False)

       On Error GoTo 0

        If IsEmpty(TryRun) Then
        Textbox2.Text = "No Match found"
        Else
        TextBox2.Value = TryRun
        End If`
Apologies in advance if I'm overlooking something rather obvious.

Comment: Please edit your post and try ti incude a image of range B14:G33. Also mention text in TextBox1 when the code was invoked or is the code is being inviked at all? May use msgbox or immidiate window to debug the values within the code.